# How to increase MEMORY_TARGET on oracle?

Tags: configuration, oracle12c

After shutting down oracle database when I was trying to startup it was showing "Specified value of MEMORY_TARGET is too small, needs to be at least 424M"

How can I increase the MEMORY_TARGET?

Thanks

Comment: Which Oracle version. Can't be 11g and 10g at the same time

Comment: The oracle version is 12c only.

Comment: check this link, https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-E6784230-0A0C-443D-8537-36FFA08A7E75.htm#ADMQS12039

Comment: Connected to an idle instance. But for any sql command it's showing " ORACLE not available"